# PHP file won't upload large file

Tags: php, apache2.4, php-5.6

I have a php file upload script that our company uses to upload files to an imaging server.  Most of those files are PDFs, TIF, and sometimes image files.  I am trying to upload a 16MB file using move_uploaded_file() and it give as error.  The $_FILES['userfile']['error'] shows code 2.  Which means that file size is too large for what the server allows.  But my php.ini settings are as follows:

```
memory_limit = 768M
post_max_size = 150M
upload_max_filesize = 150M
```

So I don't understand how my file size is too big.  I tried a 5MB file and it worked just fine.  What am I missing here?

I am running Apache 2.4.55 and PHP 5.6.1 on a Windows Machine.

I tried increasing the post_max_size and upload_max_filesize..But that did not have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

Inside my HTML form I changed

```
MAX_FILE_SIZE value="10000000"
```

to

```
value="50000000"
```

and it worked.

It's rare that we have users uploading documents that are beyond 50MB. Technically it could happen but in the last 10 years we haven't had that problem.